# Align numerator of frac

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

In my document I have following equation:

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:norm-1}
\frac{1}{2*|V|*(|V|-1)} &&& \text{mormalization for } 0^\circ \text{ and } 90^\circ\\
\label{eq:norm-2}
\frac{1}{2*(|V|-1)^2} &&& \text{mormalization for } 45^\circ \text{ and } 135^\circ
\end{align}
```

which is rendered like this:

[image]

What do I have to change im my equation to get the numerator aligned to each other so that the 1 are below each other?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How badly do you want the `*` symbols? Could you make do without them?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :) I could replace it with `\cdot` if that helps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\centeralign}[2]{%
  \eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}%
}
\newcommand{\dg}{^{\circ}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:norm-1}
&\centeralign{x}{\frac{1}{2|V|(|V|-1)}} && \text{normalization for $0\dg$ and $90\dg$} \\
\label{eq:norm-2}
&\centeralign{x}{\frac{1}{2(|V|-1)^2}}  && \text{normalization for $45\dg$ and $135\dg$}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This requires two runs to stabilize (you get warned if `eqparbox` needs another run). The first argument is an arbitrary unique string that should be in common to the boxes you need to equalize.

[image]

A couple of technical notes.

1. Multiplication is usually denote by nothing.
2. It's easier to get into math mode remaining within `\text` than closing it with adding the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fast hand held solution (the width are manual thus hand held)

I also changed the methor for displaying the angles and write the entire condition in `\text` not just the text parts (better semantics)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:norm-1}
  \mathmakebox[3cm]{\frac{1}{2*|V|*(|V|-1)}} &&& \text{mormalization for \ang{0} and
    \ang{90}}
  \\
  \label{eq:norm-2}
  \mathmakebox[3cm]{\frac{1}{2*(|V|-1)^2}} &&& \text{mormalization for \ang{45} and 
    \ang{135}}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```